# Is this possible to change flash document resources (images etc.) dynamically?

Tags: flash, animation, flash-cs5

I have created an animated banner in flash now i want to give admin access to change the images etc through admin panel dynamically. As the output of my animation developed in flash is just a single swf file...then how to do that? is this possible or not with the help of JavaScript or JQuery....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know (someone may correct me on this), I don't believe you can. Once the image is complied as part of the swf it is effectively 'baked in'. A solution would be to write the swf to dynamically load external images in from a url so that they are not baked in which then can be pointed at whatever image set by the admin.

Comment: thanks for your reply...i have searched a lot on this...you are right swf file is not editible a/c: my knowledge may be it possible with programming language like .net/java may be there some api to do this...